# PHP Array in Google Maps

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, google-maps

I'm pulling google map data into a php array from MySQL. I have used this code as a base:

https://github.com/rajkavinchetty/Google-Maps-API-with-PHP-MySQL/blob/master/index.php

It almost works perfectly. The lat/long data is pulled from the array and sets-up the markers.

```
...
$locations[]=array( 'name'=>$name, 'lat'=>$latitude, 'lng'=>$longitude, 'lnk'=>$link );
...
```

But I'm having problem with the Title/Content of the infowindow.

With the base example I'm using, the content is formatted as a link:

```
var locations = [
    <?php for($i=0;$i<sizeof($locations);$i++){ $j=$i+1;?>
    [
        'AMC Service',
        '<p><a href="<?php echo $locations[0]['lnk'];?>"><?php echo $locations[0]['name'];?></a></p>',
        <?php echo $locations[$i]['lat'];?>,
        <?php echo $locations[$i]['lng'];?>,
        0
    ]<?php if($j!=sizeof($locations))echo ","; }?>
];
```

but the variable pulls only the first link and name from the array, it does not go through the loop. I have tried many different variables, such as

```
<?php echo $locations[$i]['name'];?>
```

but this gives an error.

I'm not an expert in either php arrays or loop or java, so I'm fumbling around for clues. I've looked through all of the related questions here for help, and also consulted the Google stack as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

The first three replies were useful, thank you, but no there yet.

After the comment from Andy, and encouragement from Divyamohan that the original solution should have worked, I realised that there must be some json formatting problem, so I tried:

```
<?php echo json_encode($locations[$i]['name']);?>
```

This worked and now I'm able to have these loop through.

But still trying to get this to work as an href link. I tried to solve with backslashes as Hardik and David observed, but still this does not work. Half way there.

Comment: You have quoting issues on 2nd json line `<p>...` involving single-quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'<p><a href="<?=$locations[$i]["lnk"]?>"><?=$locations[$i]["name"]?></a></p>'
```

Just Replace this in your code and it should work.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't point out there, This "  $locations[$i]  "  part of code gonna fix this issue that @Ken is facing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this line

```
'<p><a href="<?php echo $locations[0]['lnk'];?>"><?php echo $locations[0]['name'];?></a></p>'
```

to

```
'<p><a href="<?php echo $locations[0][\'lnk\'];?>"><?php echo $locations[0][\'name\'];?></a></p>'
```

You need to add **backslash ( \ )** character to escape quote from string literals.

Answer (score 0):

So finally I found the solution to the problem. Thanks to the comments from everyone that helped me to look at it another way.

In the end, the problem was not with the code. The problem was the data. This should have been obvious. In the links column I had URLs with slashes and text in the names column included apostrophes and foreign characters. These combined were throwing off the json errors. I cleaned all the data and the modified code works perfectly.

```
<p><a href="<?=$locations[$i]['lnk']?>"><?=$locations[$i]['name']?></a></p>
```

Many thanks again for the comments.